# Will non-blocking I/O be put to sleep during copying data from kernel to user?

Tags: linux, go, io, linux-kernel, nonblocking

I ask this question because I am looking at multiplexing I/O in Go, which is using `epollwait`.

When an socket is ready, a goroutine will be waked up and begin to read socket in non-blocking mode. If the `read` system call still will be blocked during copying data from kernel to user, I assume the kernel thread the gorouine attached to will be put to sleep as well.

I am not sure of that, hoping someone can help correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fail to quite parse what you've written.

I'll try to make a sheer guess and conjure you might be overseeing the fact that the `write(2)` and `read(2)` syscalls  (and those of their ilk such as `send(2)` and `recv(2)`) on the sockets put into *non-blocking mode* are free to consume (and return, respectively) less data than requested.
In other words, a `write(2)` call on a non-blocking socket told to write 1 megabyte of data will consume just as much data currently fits into the assotiated kernel buffer and return immediately, signalling it consumed only as much data. The next immediate call to `write(2)` will likely return `EWOULDBLOCK`.

The same goes for the `read(2)` call: if you pass it a buffer large enough to hold 1 megabyte of data, and tell it to read that number of bytes, the call will only drain the contents of the kernel buffer and return immediately, signaling how much data it actually copied. The next immediate call to `read(2)` will likely return `EWOULDBLOCK`.

So, any attempt to get or put data to the socket succeeds almost immediately: either after the data had been shoveled between the kernel's buffer and the user space or right away—with the `EAGAIN` return code.

Sure, there's supposedly a possibility for an OS thread to be suspended right in the middle of performing such a syscall, but this does not count as "blocking *in* a syscall."

---

**Update** to the original answer in response to the following comment of the OP:

> <…>
>   This is what I see in book
>   "UNIX Network Programming" (Volume 1, 3rd), chapter 6.2:
>
> > A synchronous I/O operation causes the requesting process
> >     to be blocked until that I/O operation completes. Using these
> >     definitions, the first four I/O models—blocking, nonblocking, I/O
> >     multiplexing, and signal-driven I/O—are all synchronous because the
> >     actual I/O operation (recvfrom) blocks the process.
>
> It uses "blocks" to describe nonblocking I/O operation. That makes me confused.
>   I still don't understand why the book uses "blocks the process" if the process is actually not blocked.

I can only guess that the book's author intended to highlight that the process is indeed blocked since entering a syscall and until returning from it. Reads from and writes to a non-blocking socket *do block* to transfer the data, if available, between the kernel and the user space. We *colloquially* say this does not block because we mean "it does not block waiting and doing nothing for an indeterminate amount of time".

The book's author might contrast this to the so-called asynchronous I/O (called "overlapping" on Windows™)—where you basically give the kernel a buffer with/for data and ask it to do away with it completely in parallel with your code—in the sense the relevant syscall returns right away and the I/O is carried out in background (with regard to your user-space code).
To my knowledge, Go does not use kernel's async I/O facilities on neither platform it supports. You might look [there](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31908) for the developments regarding Linux and its contemporary [`io_uring` subsystem](https://lwn.net/Articles/776703/).

Oh, and one more point. The book might (at that point through the narrative at least) be discussing a simplified "classic" scheme where there are no in-process threads, and the sole unit of concurrency is the process (with a single thread of execution). In this scheme, any syscall obviously blocks the whole process. In contrast, Go works only on kernels which support threads, so in a Go program a syscall never blocks the whole process—only the thread it's called on.

---

Let me take yet another stab at explaining the problem as—I perceive—the OP stated it.

The problem of serving multiple client requests is not new—one of the more visible first statements of it is ["The C10k problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).
To quickly recap it, a single threaded server with blocking operations on the sockets it manages is only realistically able to handle a single client at a time.
To solve it, there exist two straightforward approaches:

- Fork a copy of the server process to handle each incoming client connection.
- On an OS which supports threads, fork a new thread inside the same process to handle each incoming client.

They have their pros and cons but they both suck with regard to resource usage, and—which is more important—they do not play well with the fact most clients have relatively low rate and bandwidth of I/O they perform with regard to the processing resources available on a typical server.
In other words, when serving a typical TCP/IP exchange with a client, the serving thread most of the time *sleeps* in the `write(2)` and `read(2)` calls on the client socket.
*This* is what most people mean when talking about "blocking operations" on sockets: if a socket is blocking, and operation on it will block until it can actually be carried out, and the originating thread will be put to sleep for an indeterminate amount of time.

Another important thing to note is that when the socket becomes ready, the amount of work done is typically miniscule compared to the amount of time slept between the wakeups.
While the tread sleeps, its resources (such as memory) are effectively wasted, as they cannot be used to do any other work.

Enter "polling".  It combats the problem of wasted resources by noticing that the points of readiness of networked sockets are relatively rare and far in between, so it makes sense to have lots of such sockets been served by a single thread: it allows to keep the thread almost as busy as theoretically possible, and also allows to scale out when needed: if a single thread is unable to cope with the data flow, add another thread, and so on.

This approach is definitely cool but it has a downside: the code which reads and writes data must be re-written to use callback style instead of the original plain sequential style. Writing with callbacks is hard: you usuaully have to implement intricate buffer management and state machines to deal with this.
The Go runtime solves this problem by adding another layer of scheduling for its execution flow units—goroutines: for goroutines, operations on the sockets are always blocking, but when a goroutine is about to block on a socket, this is transparently handled by suspending only the goroutine itself—until the requested operation will be able to proceed—and using the thread the goroutine was running on to do other work¹.
This allows to have the best of both approaches: the programmer may write classic no-brainer sequential callback-free networking code but the threads used to handle networking requests are fully utilized².

As to the original question of blocking, both the goroutine and the thread it runs on are indeed blocked when the data transfer on a socket is happening, but since what happens is data shoveling between a kernel and a user-space buffer, the delay is most of the time small, and is no different to the classic "polling" case.

Note that performing of syscalls—including I/O on non-pollable descriptors—in Go (at leas up until, and including Go 1.14) *does* block both the calling goroutine and the thread it runs on, but is handled differently from those of pollable descriptors: when a special monitoring thread notices a goroutine spent in a syscall more that certain amount of time (20 µs, IIRC), the runtime pulls the so-called "processor" (a runtime thing which runs goroutines on OS threads) from under the gorotuine and tries to make it run another goroutine on another OS thread; if there is a goroutine wanting to run but no free OS thread, the Go runtime creates another one.
Hence "normal" blocking I/O is still blocking in Go in both senses: it blocks both goroutines and OS threads, but the Go scheduler makes sure the program as a whole still able to make progress.

This could arguably be a perfect case for using true asynchronous I/O provided by the kernel, but it's not there yet.

---

¹ See [this classic essay](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) for more info.

² The Go runtime is certainly not the first one to pioneer this idea. For instance, look at [the State Threads library](http://state-threads.sourceforge.net) (and the more recent [`libtask`](https://swtch.com/libtask/)) which implement the same approach in plain C; the ST library has superb docs which explain the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is what I see in book UNIX Network Programming(Volume1,3rd) ,chapter 6.2  

A synchronous I/O operation causes the requesting process to be blocked until that I/O operation completes.  


Using these definitions, the first four I/O models—blocking, nonblocking, I/O multiplexing, and signal-driven I/O—are all synchronous because the actual I/O operation (recvfrom) blocks the process.

Comment: It uses "blocks" to describe nonblocking I/O operation. That makes me confused.

Comment: I still don't understand why the book uses "blocks the process" if the process is actually not blocked.

Comment: It becomes more clear now, thank you so much for these explanation

Comment: Moved the contents of my comments into the answer itself—for better visibility.

Comment: @neo, greatly expanded in an attempt to provide the whole picture's view.